# Not getting dual boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 15 alredy installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I've installed windows 10 and Ubuntu 15 on my laptop, but I don't get the dual boot menu. Ubuntu installation appeared successful, but when I turn my laptop on, it goes straight to Windows without giving me the option to choose ubuntu. It's a brand new laptop, so still don't have any data I'm worried about losing.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://askubuntu.com/questions/700949/dual-booting-ubuntu-and-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Go to your BIOS settings (press Esc, F2, etc. it depends on your manufacturer) and check the boot order. 'ubuntu' should be one of the options. Set it as the top boot priority. If it's not there, grub may not have installed correctly.

Comment: I've checked BIOS straight away and nothing. Re-installed Ubuntu about 3 times, but always get the same problem. What can I do?

Comment: Most likely it's grub. When you install grub during the Ubuntu installation, make sure to install it to the hard drive (eg. /dev/sda) and not any partition on the drive (such as /dev/sda1).

Comment: I've replaced Ubuntu 15 for Ubuntu 14, to see if it made a difference, during the installation it was going on sda. Still nothing! How do I solve this problem? I need help!

Comment: Try something different. Make a small partition (~200MB should do it) and note the partition number (/dev/sda#). This time, set grub to install to that partition and see if that helps.